# Casting Java functional interface

Tags: java, functional-interface

I have a functional interface Test and an object (test) implemented it. Then with the HttpServletRequest request.setAttribute method I set it as an attribute. When I am trying to get back this attribute in a JSP file with the request.getAttribute method I got a ClassCastException error.
ListProductsServlet$$Lambda$37/186880189 cannot be cast to Test.

Is it possible to add lambda expression for request as an attribute and get it back? I searched for solutions but I have not find any.

```
public interface Test<Product> {
    boolean func(Product p);
}

Test<Product> test = new Test<Product>() {
        @Override
        public boolean func(Product p) {
            return search == null || search.equals("") ? true : p.filterProducts("display");
        }
    };

request.setAttribute("test", test); //OK in servlet

Test test = (Test) request.getAttribute("test"); //ClassCastException
```

Comment: Are you sure the class the attribute gets cast to is the same `Test<Product>` interface, or the second `Test` refers a quite different type because of possible typo in the `import`s section?

Comment: Additionally, if I'm correct, the `test` implementation from your code is not a lambda as your exception message is telling. Not very accurate.

Comment: Yes, the implementation of test in servlet and the casting in jsp uses the same Test<Product> interface. The project compile I get this exception in runtime. If I know well the Java compiler compile the functional interfaces to lamba expression. I do not use lambda in this project because of Java code version problem of GlassFish.

Comment: What is the `test.getClass().getInterfaces()` output right before you put it to the request attribute holder?

Comment: Sorry! Your suspicion was confirmed. The two objects did not referred to the same Test<Product> interface. Thanks! Problem solved!